# Save Case Comment in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customer-community, case-comment

My requirement is to save case comment in customer portal. I have three lightning components in one single page. One of the component is case detail component. When I try to save comment from community portal the Comment Body value is not passing to controller but record is saving for particular case and the comment body value will be null.
How to resolve this plz somebody help.

Thanks in advance.......

Component

```
<!-- Include Static Resource-->
<ltng:require styles="/resource/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
              scripts="/resource/bootstrap/js/jquery.js,/resource/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>


<aura:attribute name="casenocreated" type="String" />
<!-- Define Attribute-->
<aura:attribute name="commentsection" type="CaseComment" />
<!-- here c:CaseSelected is another component -->
<aura:handler event="c:CaseSelected" action="{!c.getcaseid}"/>

<div style="height:150px">
    <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small" style="text-align: center;background-color:LightGray;">
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div><lightning:icon iconName="standard:report" alternativeText="Event" size="small"/>
            </div>
            <div><h6>&nbsp; ACTIVITY FEED </h6></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="form-group" style="align:left;width:1050px">
                        <label >Comments</label>
                        <ui:inputText class="form-control" value="{!v.commentsection.CommentBody}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="align:right;padding-top:16px;">
                    <lightning:button class="btn btn-info" variant="brand" label="Save" onclick="{!c.create}" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

Controller.js

```
({
getcaseid :function(component, event) {

    var caseselectedevent = event.getParam("caseselectedevent"); 

    //  alert('description:   '+caseselectedevent );
    if(caseselectedevent != undefined) 
    {
        component.set("v.casenocreated", caseselectedevent.CaseNumber);  
        //   alert('parameter is not undefined'+ caseselectedevent.CaseNumber );
    }
    else
    {
        //  alert('parameter is undefined');
    }

},
create :function(component, event) {
    alert('something...');
    var commentsection = component.get("v.commentbody");

    var caseid = component.get("v.casenocreated");
   alert(commentsection +' '+ caseid);
    var action = component.get('c.savecomments');
    action.setParams({
        comments : "comments",
        caseid : "caseid"
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
            //component.set("v.commentsection");
            alert('Comment saved successfully: '+ commentsection);
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    //  alert('case comments:'+ caseselectedevent + comments);


}
```

})

Save Comment method in apex class

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void savecomments(String comments, String caseid)
{
    List<Case> caselist = [SELECT id, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber =:caseid];
    id caseno = caselist[0].id;
    //List<CaseComment> casecom = [SELECT CommentBody,Id,ParentId FROM CaseComment WHERE ParentId =:caseno];
    if (caselist.size() > 0)
    {
        CaseComment a = new CaseComment(ParentId = caseno, CommentBody = comments);
        insert a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to post your code?

Answer (score 0):

In the method `create`,  for the statement

`action.setParams({
        comments : "comments",
        caseid : "caseid"
    });`

The value comments is a String and the case id is also a String. They both should be variables. Seems like your case record is not being updated because the apex controller would not have been able to find any id related to that case.

Try making changes to your code like:

`var caseId = component.get( 'v.caseId' );
var comments = component.get( 'v.comments' ); //This was missing
var action = component.get( 'c.action' );
action.setParams({
    comments : comments,
    caseid : caseId
});`

Comment: Still the comment body value is null...

Comment: You can try the following: #1 Check if there is a permission issue. You can go to the standard edit page and look if you can manually update the comments. #2 try using `System.debug()` or `console.log` for any errors

Comment: I have checked all the possibilities, Its not working if I run this component from lightning app the comment body is coming in alert but when I try it with customer portal its not working even though I have given all the permissions.